# GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER - OpenGL ES 3

Tags: ios, opengl-es

W want to use `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER` in my GL ES 3 app. Based on documentation (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/html/glTexParameter.xhtml), it seems to be supported, however, on iOS this `#define` is not present. Is it named differently? Maybe some extension?

Comment: @shallowThought - not relevant for ES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER became legal in GL ES 3.2 ([link to specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/es_spec_3.2.pdf)), but may otherwise be available by one (or more) of the following extensions:

- [GL_NV_texture_border_clamp](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_texture_border_clamp.txt)
- [GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_border_clamp.txt)
- [GL_OES_texture_border_clamp](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_texture_border_clamp.txt)

In the absence of one (or more) of these extensions, or if using an earlier version of GL ES, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER mode is *not* specified, and specifying a non-zero *border* value with your glTexImage parameters is documented to generate a GL_INVALID_VALUE error.

You are evidently working from an out-of-date header file, but you should also check that your hardware and driver are compatible.